# F# Web Role Azure

Tags: f#, azure, websharper

I'd like to create a web application with websharper in F#. Azure 1.4 SDK only includes a F# worker role. How can I create a Azure web role in F#?

Does anybody know how to create a template or change the language of a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a webapplication then it should be easy to use it as a web role - you don't need the template - see
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/02/05/using-an-existing-asp-net-web-application-as-a-windows-azure-web-role.aspx

If you can deploy your F# to a typical IIS box, then you should be able to deploy to Azure too.

For more info, on using F# with ASP.Net - [F# and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135959/f-and-asp-net) - but I'd guess from your post you don't need this!

Please do blog about your experience!